# Несколько BackgroundWorker не возвращают вычисляемые значения полностью при большом объёме данных

Tags: c#, массивы, многопоточность, backgroundworker

Я создаю программу для чтения и редактирования файлов. Она читает файл, затем преобразуя его в последовательность нулей и единиц.
Из-за того, что я рассчитывал на обработку больших объёмов данных, то преобразование файла я доверил 16ти BackgroundWorker. Однако я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что если размер файла превышает 2 килобайта, то небольшая часть данных теряется. Я не знаю, с чем это связано, так что выложил этот вопрос сюда.
В общем, сначала файл считывается и заносится в массивы по 1\16 части в каждый
, кроме последнего, в него заносятся все оставшиеся символы.При необходимости (размер файла превышает 32768 байтов) файл делится на части по 32768 символов по такому же принципу:

```
    void ShowFileOpenDialog(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DialogResult.OK == FileOpenDialog.ShowDialog()) {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(FileOpenDialog.FileName, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                RawCommonFile = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(RawCommonFile.Length));
            if(RawCommonFile.Length >= 16) {
                FilePart = 1;
                if (RawCommonFile.Length > 32768) { FullCommonFile = RawCommonFile.Substring(0,32768);AllFileParts = (int)Math.Floor((double)RawCommonFile.Length / 32768);}
                else { FullCommonFile = RawCommonFile; AllFileParts = 1; }
            FileReadProgressBar.Maximum = RawCommonFile.Length;
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(RawCommonFile.Length));
            CommonFile[0] = FullCommonFile.Substring(0, Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length) / 16)));
            CommonFile[1] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[2] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 2))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[3] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 3))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[4] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 4))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[5] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 5))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[6] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 6))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[7] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 7))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[8] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 8))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[9] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 9))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[10] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 10))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[11] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 11))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[12] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 12))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[13] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 13))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[14] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 14))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[15] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 15))), FullCommonFile.Length - Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 15))));
            BinaryFile[0] = "";
            BinaryFile[1] = "";
            BinaryFile[2] = "";
            BinaryFile[3] = "";
            BinaryFile[4] = "";
            BinaryFile[5] = "";
            BinaryFile[6] = "";
            BinaryFile[7] = "";
            BinaryFile[8] = "";
            BinaryFile[9] = "";
            BinaryFile[10] = "";
            BinaryFile[11] = "";
            BinaryFile[12] = "";
            BinaryFile[13] = "";
            BinaryFile[14] = "";
            BinaryFile[15] = "";
            CharProgress = 0;
            FileBox.Text = "";
            FileReader.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader2.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader3.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader4.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader5.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader6.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader7.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader8.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader9.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader10.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader11.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader12.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader13.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader14.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader15.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader16.RunWorkerAsync();
            MainMenu.Enabled = false;
            FileBox.Enabled = false;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            ProgressPanel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Затем все BackgroundWorker начинают работать:

```
    void OpenFileAsync(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[0]) {
            BinaryFile[0] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
                if (CharProgress % 8 == 0) { FileReadProgressBar.Value += 8;FileReadProgressLabel.Text = "Reading char " + Convert.ToString(FileReadProgressBar.Value) + " of " + Convert.ToString(FileReadProgressBar.Maximum);
                }
                CharProgress++;
        }
    }

    void FileOpened(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync2(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[1]) {
                BinaryFile[1] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
                CharProgress++;
        }
    }

    void FileOpened2(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync3(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[2]) {
                BinaryFile[2] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
                CharProgress++;
            }           
    }

    void FileOpened3(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync4(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(char sb in CommonFile[3]) {
                BinaryFile[3] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
                CharProgress++; 
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened4(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync5(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(char sb in CommonFile[4]) {
            BinaryFile[4] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++; 
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened5(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync6(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[5]) {
            BinaryFile[5] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++; 
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened6(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync7(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[6]) {
            BinaryFile[6] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++; 
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened7(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync8(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[7]) {
            BinaryFile[7] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++;
        }       
    }

    void FileOpened8(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync9(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[8]) {
            BinaryFile[8] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++; 
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened9(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync10(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(char sb in CommonFile[9]) {
            BinaryFile[9] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++;     
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened10(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync11(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(char sb in CommonFile[10]) {
            BinaryFile[10] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++; 
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened11(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync12(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[11]) {
            BinaryFile[11] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++; 
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened12(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync13(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[12]) {
            BinaryFile[12] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++;     
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened13(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync14(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[13]) {
            BinaryFile[13] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++;
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened14(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync15(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[14]) {
            BinaryFile[14] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++;                 
        }           
    }

    void FileOpened15(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JoinBinary();
    }

    void OpenFileAsync16(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char sb in CommonFile[15]) {
            BinaryFile[15] += Convert.ToString(sb, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            CharProgress++;
        }
    }
```

Далее при завершении работы каждого BackgroundWorker специальная переменная увеличивается до тех пор, пока не становится равна количеству всех потоков, а далее весь код добавляется в текстовое поле FileBox:

```
    void JoinBinary()
    {
        ReadPartsCount++;
        if (ReadPartsCount == 16) {
            MessageBox.Show("char progress : " + Convert.ToString(CharProgress) + " of " + Convert.ToString(CommonFile[0].Length + CommonFile[1].Length + CommonFile[2].Length + CommonFile[3].Length + CommonFile[4].Length + CommonFile[5].Length + CommonFile[6].Length + CommonFile[7].Length + CommonFile[8].Length + CommonFile[9].Length + CommonFile[10].Length + CommonFile[11].Length + CommonFile[12].Length + CommonFile[13].Length + CommonFile[14].Length + CommonFile[15].Length));
            MainMenu.Enabled = true;
            FileBox.Enabled = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable; 
            FileBox.Text = BinaryFile[0];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[1];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[2];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[3];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[4];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[5];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[6];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[7];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[8];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[9];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[10];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[11];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[12];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[13];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[14];
            FileBox.Text += BinaryFile[15];
            if (FilePart != AllFileParts) {
            FilePart++;
                if (FilePart + 1 != AllFileParts) {
                FullCommonFile = RawCommonFile.Substring((FilePart - 1) * 32768,32768);}
            else {FullCommonFile = RawCommonFile.Substring((FilePart - 1) * 32768,RawCommonFile.Length - ((FilePart - 1) * 32768));
            }
            BinaryFile[0] = "";
            BinaryFile[1] = "";
            BinaryFile[2] = "";
            BinaryFile[3] = "";
            BinaryFile[4] = "";
            BinaryFile[5] = "";
            BinaryFile[6] = "";
            BinaryFile[7] = "";
            BinaryFile[8] = "";
            BinaryFile[9] = "";
            BinaryFile[10] = "";
            BinaryFile[11] = "";
            BinaryFile[12] = "";
            BinaryFile[13] = "";
            BinaryFile[14] = "";
            BinaryFile[15] = "";
            CommonFile[0] = FullCommonFile.Substring(0,Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length) / 16)));
            CommonFile[1] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[2] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 2))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[3] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 3))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[4] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 4))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[5] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 5))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[6] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 6))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[7] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 7))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[8] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 8))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[9] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 9))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[10] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 10))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[11] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 11))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[12] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 12))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[13] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 13))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[14] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 14))), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16))));
            CommonFile[15] = FullCommonFile.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 15))), FullCommonFile.Length - Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(FullCommonFile.Length / 16 * 15))));
            CharProgress = 0;       
            FileReader.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader2.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader3.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader4.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader5.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader6.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader7.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader8.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader9.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader10.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader11.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader12.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader13.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader14.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader15.RunWorkerAsync();
            FileReader16.RunWorkerAsync();      
            }
            else{
                ProgressPanel.Visible = false;
            }
            ReadPartsCount = 0;
            }
    }

MessageBox.Show("char progress : " + Convert.ToString(CharProgress) + " of " + Convert.ToString(CommonFile[0].Length + CommonFile[1].Length + CommonFile[2].Length + CommonFile[3].Length + CommonFile[4].Length + CommonFile[5].Length + CommonFile[6].Length + CommonFile[7].Length + CommonFile[8].Length + CommonFile[9].Length + CommonFile[10].Length + CommonFile[11].Length + CommonFile[12].Length + CommonFile[13].Length + CommonFile[14].Length + CommonFile[15].Length));
```

Я использовал для отладки. В маленьких файлах символы присутствовали все, в больших же их немного не хватало.

Comment: ...вам нужно выбросить текущую реализацию и переписать все с 0